# jQuery: can't alter externally loaded content

Tags: jquery

**ISSUE:** We are building a website on a very restricted CMS. We need to replace a certain function in anchor's href. Unfortunately, the content loaded is external and this piece of code does not work:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*="show_upsell_dialog"]').each(function(e){
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('show_upsell_dialog(', 'more_details_1('));
    });   
});
```

HTML bit:

```
<a href="javascript:show_upsell_dialog(1238)">Details</a>
```

**QUESTION:** Why? How do i make it work?

Comment: What happens instead? And if this data is loaded externally, is this piece of code being called before the data is actually loaded?

Comment: first of all, you don't need the if ($('a[href*="show_upsell_dialog"]').length) statement - if no match for .each is returned, replacement will not occur

Comment: Nothing happens instead. Looks like my code cannot see the externally loaded content - probably because it is loaded after my code is loaded...

Comment: @chuckfinley -- Can we see the code to load the external content?

Comment: @tymeJV http://hastebin.com/riwuleyega.coffee

Comment: Throw this code inside your `$.get` callback

Comment: I can't make alterations to the code provided in the hastebin. As i said - the CMS is very restricted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get access to the $.get or the promise returned by the $.get, your options are very limited.

An alternative is to use a global ajax callback that unbinds itself when a request with the expected options is called.

```
function completeCallback (e, xhr, options) {
    // updated
    if (options.url == "/ejax-order-step/") {
        $(e.currentTarget).off('ajaxComplete',completeCallback);
        $('a[href*="show_upsell_dialog"]').attr('href',function(href){
            return href.replace('show_upsell_dialog(', 'more_details_1(');
        });
    }
}
$(document).ajaxComplete(completeCallback);
```

Note however, it is required for this callback to be defined before the request it's listening for is complete.

In your case though, i don't see why you cant just do this:

```
window.show_upsell_dialog = window.more_details_1;
```

Comment: Although... Are you using this to replace Every occurrence of an anchor tag calling the `show_upsell_dialog`? Why not just override that function with your own instead? It is defined on the window after all.

Comment: You don't need to see the function to replace it. see update. If it's on the window (which is has to be to be called in that way), you have full access to it.

Comment: Edit: good idea! Will just move the .js insertion to the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's going to depend heavily on when and how often the show_upsell_dialog function is defined though.

Comment: It's just that particular tab :)

Comment: Could not override the function but the ajaxComplete() did the job

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code :

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="show_upsell_dialog"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('show_upsell_dialog', 'more_details_1'))
    });
})
```

Comment: yes i know, but that did not help. I updated my question and added a piece of HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

Give your function a name and call it within 
setTimeout(yourFuncName, 1000);

If 1 seconds too short try 2. I'm just guessing but setTimeout is helpful sometimes...

Comment: I hope you are not serious